# openvpn connection without forwarding all traffic

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, route

I am trying to connect a client to a vpn network without openvpn forwarding all my traffic into the network. The point being is I want to be able to connect and communicate with all the other connected vpn machines and their services, but I want all my regular traffic (http, etc) leaving and entering through my default route/network like it normally would when not connected to the vpn.

Here are my configs and routes if they help any (all routes relating to tun0 are added by openvpn):

```
user@machine:~# ip route
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.9 dev tun0
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  proto static
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.9 dev tun0
10.8.0.9 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.10
xx.xx.xx.xx via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.9 dev tun0
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.187
192.168.80.0/24 dev wlan0-1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.80.1
```

I have tried to use the route-nopull config option, and while I was able to connect to the vpn and obtain an ip address, other vpn users were not able access my services such as ssh. If I removed the route-nopull option they can access my ssh service, but now all of the boxes traffic is now being redirected through the vpn.

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xx.xx.xx.xx YYYYY
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo
verb 3
ca ca.crt
cert vpn.crt
```

Overall I am looking for a way to connect to the vpn network and allow other vpn users access my services without redirecting all my regular traffic into the vpn network.

Hopefully what I am trying to achieve makes sense.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is set in the _server_ configuration, not in the _client_ configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton so there is no way to achieve this on the client side? Not even through editing of the routing or iptables?

Answer (score 1):

On the client you can use `--route-up` script:

```
ip route del 0.0.0.0/1
ip route del 128.0.0.0/1
exit 0
```

Using also `--route-noexec` option, you can write a script to add routes conditionally - ie. all except *0.0.0.0/1* and *128.0.0.0/1*. Routes can be read from environment variables. This is harder than blind removal, as it needs some processing logic in the script.